# Try and Except in a While Loop

Tags: python

I have a hard time evaluating this `while` loop.

To my understanding, any value NOT 1,2,3 will test Boolean `True` and restart the loop.

My question is **why** values 1, 2, 3 test Boolean `False` and end the loop?

I think the **`except:`** statement has something to do with it.

```
def get_player_input():
    while True:
        print
        player = raw_input( "Enter 1 for Rock 2 for paper or 3 for Scissors: " )
        try:
            player = int(player)
            if player in ( 1, 2, 3 ):
                return player
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print "Please enter a number from 1 to 3."

get_player_input()
```

Comment: Hint: the `ValueError` is related (only) with the `int` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement *leaves the function*, returning its value. Once you encounter that statement (when `player` is `1`, `2`, or `3`), any loops (or other control structures within the function) are "broken" by virtue of the fact that you're no longer in the `get_player_input` function.

The `except` statement has nothing to do with it: that's just there to deal with inputs that can't be parsed into integers.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I replaced the `return` with `print "yay"` and now im stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes. May add     `except KeyboardInterrupt: return ( "Ctrl-C terminated ... " )`

Comment: @user3666197 Care to elaborate?

Comment: @user3666197 I added it in and I don't know what it does. My guess is that if the user clicks cancel on the input box, it returns "Control-C terminated..." but that doesn't happen when I try.

Comment: @bLunt I think @user3666197 was suggesting a way to cleanly break out of the infinite loop, by capturing the `Ctrl+C` keyboard interrupt. But given that you probably don't actually *want* the infinite loop, you probably don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

After removing the return to break ask the user to input `e` and use a `break` or `return`

```
def get_player_input():
    while True:
        print
        player = raw_input( "Enter 1 for Rock 2 for paper or 3 for Scissors or e to exit: " )
        if player == "e":
            print("Goodbye")
            break #  or return
        try:
            player = int(player)
            if player in (1, 2, 3 ):
                print "yay"
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print "Please enter a number from 1 to 3."
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is correct. Rememebr you need 2 to play rock-paper-scissors. You have a function to accept  input for one player. Now you need to take two inputs and do a comparison and reutrn a result:

```
def oneBetterThanTwo(one, two):
    # finish this function
    return True # or False

players = ['player1', 'player2']
inps = [get_player_input() for p in players]

print (players[0] if oneBetterThanTwo(*inps) else players[1]), 'won'
```

I leave it to you to finish the function ...